# How to mark in a json file which schema describes it

Tags: json

My goal is simple: I want to know what schema describes the given json file, meaning I need to mark it somehow. Example:

```json
{
    "Id": 100,
    "name": "example"
}
```

What is not clear from the example below is what schema definition describes it, in other words what are the required fields and what are the other fields available in it.

I'm looking not only for validation, but rather ease-of-work with this jsonn file. For example, I'd like to use it as a configuration file. I need to know what properties are available and what properties are mandatory.

I'm looking for something like this:

```json
{
    "$schemaDefinition": "URL to the schema definition",
    "Id": 100,
    "name": "example"
}
```

What I don't know is what is the valid way doing it. I read through back and forth the [json-schema.org](https://json-schema.org/) but it doesn't discusses this. However, I remember I saw this solution somewhere.

As a result, I hope..., editor can pick up the schema and provide intellisense. Or the poor person who is going to work with the json file (configure something) knows where to look for available and mandatory configuration properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it.

```json
{
    "$schema": "URL to the schema definition",
    "Id": 100,
    "name": "example"
}
```

If the schema file is stored in Github you have to use the url to the raw content.
Jetbrains products can pick up the schema definition without any problem.